# Delete Image from Local path using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Here is the Method using for saving Image to my local system using Spring MVC

```
private void saveProductImage(Product product)
    {
        System.out.println("Product Image - "+ product.getProduct_image());
            try{
                if(product.getProduct_image()!= null)
                {
                    Path path=Paths.get("E://Eclipse//WorkSpace//TechGrab//src//main//webapp//resources//images//product-images//"+ product.getProduct_id()+".png");
                    product.getProduct_image().transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
                    System.out.println("Product Image Saved !!!");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to Save image !!");
            }
    }
```

here The **Product** is the My Model, and  *path* is the object of **Path** where im saving the image as the product ID od the image using

```
product.getProduct_image().transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
```

Now - i would Like to delete the Product details along with the Product Image, so here is my Product Details getting deleted with this

```
@Transactional
    public void deleteProduct(String product_id) {
        Session ses = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tr = ses.beginTransaction();
        Product temp = ses.get(Product.class, product_id);
        ses.delete(temp);
        tr.commit();
        ses.close();

    }
```

which is getting the delete method for the product Id but now still the image is been saved in the local system with the product id , how can i delete the Product Image ! Help me out ty :)

I have tried this - but its not working !

```
private void deleteProductImage(Product product)
    {
        System.out.println("Product Image - "+ product.getProduct_image());
            try{
                if(product.getProduct_image()!= null)
                {
                    Path path=Paths.get("E://Eclipse//WorkSpace//TechGrab//src//main//webapp//resources//images//product-images//"+ product.getProduct_id()+".png");
                    Files.delete(path);
                    System.out.println("Product Image Deleted !!!");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to Delete image !!");
            }
    }
```

sorry for bad English

Comment: you save on file system.. and delete from database.. dont get that

Comment: i save on my system not on the database

Comment: well check the path - E://Eclipse//WorkSpace//TechGrab//src//main//webapp//resources//images//product-images//"+ product.getProduct_id()+".png"    where the image is getting saved in the system with the product id of the product

Comment: Just delete the file after deleting the product in the database.

Comment: Not possible to deleting file manually as it is a Spring MVC

Answer (score 2):

Oh, finally got the simplist Solution !
my bad , forget things xD

Thought the answer was

```
@Transactional
    private void deleteProductImage(Product product)
    {
         try { 
             File file = new File("E://Eclipse//WorkSpace//TechGrab//src//main//webapp//resources//images//product-images//"+ product.getProduct_id()+".png");
             if(file.delete()) { 
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
             } else {
                System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
                }
          }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to Delete image !!");
            }
    }
```

Ty ! Post closed

Comment: Thanks save time today.